# "takeWhile is not a function" while using with IntervalObservable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this simple setup in my Angular 2 code:

```
IntervalObservable.create(5000)
  .takeWhile(() => this.spinnerOn) // only fires when component is alive
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.httpService.pollResults()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  });
```

The code compiles, and i can see the takeWhile.d.ts used from rxjs node module in my IDE (IDEA). But when the app runs, i see this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_observable_IntervalObservable__.a.create(...).takeWhile is not a function
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to import the **`takeWhile`** operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
```

If you are using rxjs 5.5 and above

```
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: this was the fastest true answer i got till now :) thanks !!

Comment: I'm using rxjs 5.5.2 and 2nd import didn't work for me. Used the first approach

Comment: I am using the same 'v5.5.2' and got the error for the second. First one solved it for me too. Thanks @Sajeetharan and Nouman